# IBM Cognos Analytics Selecting top 2 from a dataset

Tags: sql, max, report, cognos, cognos-bi

I'm working on a report where I need data for current week, and the week before, and compare these two. I have a week column in my data, which are transactions, So my data looks something like:

```
Amount - Week
13     - 01
19     - 01
11     - 02
10     - 02
13     - 02
12     - 03
18     - 03
15     - 04
```

And I want to this as a result from the two most recent weeks and sum of Amount:

```
Week 03: 30
Week 04: 15
```

Now it easy to get the most recent week, just a maximum (Week for report), but when I want to select the 2nd largest I'm getting stuck.

I've tried to do a filter that is basically "Maximum( case when week = maximum(week) then null else week)", but either I have not figured out the syntax or I this approach does not work.

Other alternative which I tired was the rank() feature and then a query which selects rank in (1, 2) but for whatever reason I couldn't get this approach to work and only got the error

```
The function "to_char" is being used for local processing but is not available as a built-in function, or at least one of its parameters is not supported.
```

Which I believe has something to do with the aggregation (multiple records per occurence of week). Anyway I'm kind of stuck and the error messages aren't giving me any clues. Would very much appreicate some help!

Comment: Crosstab?  I'm not seeing from your question why a crosstab would be needed.  It looks like you need a list.  How about a sample report built on the samples that demonstrates the problem.  You can publish the report spec to pastebin.

Comment: dougp - Anton stated "And I want to build a cross tab from the two most recent weeks and sum of Amount:"

Comment: Yes, but the example output provided is simply WeekNum, SUM(Amount).  That's easily done in a list.  I don't see any technical reason to use a crosstab.  There's some layer of complexity that I'm not seeing.  The reason I mention it is that this is really easy to do in the query, the pump to a list.  Sure a crosstab would be just as easy at that point, but I'm not seeing the need.  And without that, any solution I might provide would likely be too simple to meet the requirements of the unseen complexities.

Comment: My bad, edited the question. In my case I\m working with a cross tab but for the sake of the example it is not relevant. Any input on the question though?

Comment: Let me know if I am close, is the issue "finding the 2nd largest"?   For example, sort in size order would have the largest entry with a running_count of 1.  If so, the second largest would be running_count of 2.  You could filter AFTER Aggregation  running_count <= 2

Comment: The error message is related to something you have coded into a filter or data item expression - something you have not shown us.  Please reproduce the problem using the samples and post the report spec.

Comment: What do you mean by "and compare these two"?  Do you simply want to see them near each other on the report, or should some math be performed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RANK` should work fine, but it may not work well if you try to get Cognos to do all of the work in one place.  I thought I could filter on the ranked data item and set the Application property to After auto aggregation.  But I got strange results.

Rather than trying to create one complicated solution, try breaking the problem into smaller, simpler components.

Define Query1
Data Items:
Week = [namespace].[query subject].[Week]
Amount = [namespace].[query subject].[Amount] with the detail aggregation set to Total
Rank = rank([namespace].[query subject].[Week])

Create Query2 and set Query1 as its source.
Data Items:
[Query1].[Week]
[Query1].[Amount]
Detail Filters:
[Query1].[Rank] <= 2

Use Query2 as the source for your list.